# In Unix, how can I register to know when a process is launched?

Tags: unix, process, exec, fork

Let's say I want to have a background process which writes to a file every time a process is launched or exits. Any process (though I'm mostly interested in those with graphical components).

I'd rather not constantly poll the list of running process. My is that I'd have to replace exec or fork with my own copy, but I'm not sure how that's done. Or is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way to monitor this without modifying the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on what you want exactly, but it sounds like either user accounting or running audit.
The problem is these are UNIX flavor specific.  Please tell us what OS you have.

Do you want this information for all users?  A group?

Some UNIX flavors let you monitor file system activity (like Linux inotify), so if you know what code users are going to run ahead of time, you can try monitoring specific files for execute.  This might be easier than implementing audit or some kind of accounting.  We need a lot more specifics to really be of any help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I have Ubuntu 10.10, but I'd rather keep it as general as possible.

This would be for a single user.

All I want, at this most general, is to know when a process was started and when it exited.
The example I gave in the original post should be general enough for what I want: whenever a process is started, I log the timestamp and its image name to a certain file. Same whenever it exits.